# access my docker mysql container in java class

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm leaning docker and trying to connect a db in my java application.

I already create the container and started it

5621fc9b438d mysql/mysql-server:latest   "/entrypoint.sh mysq   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    3306/tcp            mysql-db

I also accessed the container and create one database by bash. I'm having problem to connect the db on Java class.

My Java method

```
 @Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb");
    dataSource.setUsername("mysql-db");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    return dataSource;
}
```

How can I connect and use my docker mysql database on Java application?

Comment: Do you have to specify the port# to 'setUrl'?

Comment: yes,  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have open your port `3306` to the outside with `-p 3306:3306` (not just `-p 3306`). By default, only linked container will be able to access your mysql port.

Finally, if you are running Docker with a docker-machine, you will need to speficy the ip generated for the Docker VM rather than `localhost`.

Good luck.